# apple developer account which should I use for develp Apps?

Tags: react-native, apple-developer

I want to develop an E-commerce app and what do deploy and code on my app but I have to buy a apple developer member ship.

I get asked for this:

I develop apps for:
-Individual/ Sole Proprietor
-Company/Organization
-Nonprofit (so this can be away)
-Accredited Educational Institution
-Government Organisation

Which should I use  for (E-commerce or social media)?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you make a `Company/Organization` for this you're going to need at least an `llc` registering your business in whatever state your'e in. Furthermore, your business needs a `duns number` this is like your business social security number. Lastly, you need a `business email` and a `website`. That's all you need to make `Company/Organization` on apple developer account. In addition if your going to sell stuff on your app you need a `privacy policy` and a `terms of conditions`

**But why should you do Company/Organization?**

1. LLC owners are protected from personal liability for business debts and claims
2. Tax write offs for your business
3. And opportunity for small business grants from the government

---

Really the reason I got it so If my app ever got sued I wouldn't be liable for it my bussiness would